# Quarkus does not @Inject beans in @QuarkusTest suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, quarkus

I am pretty new in Quarkus but I'm pretty proficient in other IoC frameworks (Spring). I have a bean declared as follow

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestingRepo {
    public String greet() {
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

and I do also have a Quarkus test that looks like this

```
@QuarkusTest
public class InjectionTest {

    @Inject
    public TestingRepo tr;

    @Test
    public void testInjection() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(tr);
    }
}
```

When I do `mvn test` I got:

```
[ERROR] testInjection  Time elapsed: 0.006 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>
     at org.mytest.InjectionTest.testInjection(InjectionTest.java:25)
```

There is something I'm missing? I'm expecting to have the bean injected and not being `null`!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This looks correct on the first sight. Do you have a complete but minimal reproducer somewhere?

Comment: not really, I am trying to do that... seems that `quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.1.Final` also fails to build new projects now, just using `1.11.2.Final` seems working but is another version... i will try the old way, reboot & retry

Comment: Can you take a look at the application startup logs (you still get those even with tests) and see if there's any stacktrace indicating a failure to inject?

Answer (score 4):

`@QuarkusTest` only kicks off with JUnit Jupiter.

You don't have the import lines in your example, but I'd guess you have:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

and changing to

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem - and import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; was already there.

But I noticed that VSCode - for whatever reason  - imported

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
```

Changing this to

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
```

fixed the problem. The injected Bean was no longer null.

Comment: This happens with me all the time!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with Quarkus unit tests. I found a workaround for my current situation that may work here.

I have a config class with several `@Produces` methods and a unit test which injects one of them as a field. With just `@Produces` and `@Inject`, the field remained `null`. Adding `@Named` to both the method and injection point fixed it.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConfig {
   @Produces
   @Named("mySpecialBean")
   public MySpecialBean mySpecialBean() {
      return new MySpecialBean();
   }
}
```

```java
@QuarkusTest
public class MyTest {
   @Inject
   @Named("mySpecialBean")
   MySpecialBean mySpecialBean;

  ...
}
```